# Twitter Application using php?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I need to develope a Twitter application in php,
Requirements are that that my application should get access token from user and then using that access token, my application should be able to get backup of the twitter user tweets, followers list, timeline, messages etc.
I created an application on twitter and got the consumer key and secret.
Please tell me how i start now, and what is the best php library that will be enough for my requirements.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best place to start is http://dev.twitter.com

If you want to really jump into things, check out the listing of PHP libraries that you can use: http://dev.twitter.com/pages/libraries#php

**Edit:** I also suggest you read everything under *Guidelines and Terms*, *Authentication*, and *REST API & General* on this page: http://dev.twitter.com/doc